# Selecting data frame rows in repetitive manner

Tags: python, pandas

i have a data set similar to

```
    name     2016 2017 2018 2019
0 google     nil  nil  nil  nil
1 investment  56   61   62  68
2 expense     23   25   32  45
3 research    19   22   25  37
4 rating      9    9     9   9
5 microsoft   nil  nil  nil  nil
6 investment  60   70   69  81
7 expense     50   60   70  80
8 research    9   15    21  23
9 rating      9    9     9   9
10 apple      nil  nil  nil  nil
11 investment  90   90   92  92
12 expense     56   55   54  54
13 research    2    3    2   6
14 rating      9    8    9   9
```

i want to create a similar dataframe from this but only specific data , selecting only the rows with name, research and then calculating balance by subtracting investment from expense. example output

```
name     2016 2017 2018 2019
0 google     nil  nil  nil  nil
1 balance     33  36   30   33
2 research    19   22   25  37
```

and so on, i have tried using mathematical calculation a with a for loop  and `df.iloc[c]` but not have nay luck with it..any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I saw this question yesterday but had no much of a chance to give it a good try.
I have a possible solution for you, as long as the model follows the structure you've printed.

```
# variables
name = []
balance = []
research = []
ars = np.array([])
l_array = []

co = int(df.shape[0]/5) #every 5 rows a company 

for model,index in zip(df.values,df.index): #model is numpy.ndarray

    # Company name will always be in range +5 (like,0,5,10...)
    ranger   = [(lambda x: x*5)(x) for x in range(co)]
    rangei   = [(lambda x: x*5+1)(x) for x in range(co)]
    rangee   = [(lambda x: x*5+2)(x) for x in range(co)]
    rangere  = [(lambda x: x*5+3)(x) for x in range(co)]

    if index in ranger:

        name = model[0:] #everything

    if index in rangei:

        inv = model[1:] #values after name

    if index in rangee:

        exp = model[1:] #values after name
        val_bal = np.subtract(inv,exp)
        balance = np.insert(val_bal, 0, 'balance', axis=0)

    if index in rangere:

        research = model[0:] #everything
        ars = np.concatenate((name,balance,research))
        l_array.append(ars)
```

You can go from here to split the dataframe or you can keep it this way and have companies information in a single line.

```
new_df= pd.DataFrame(list(map(np.ravel, l_array)))

        0    1    2    3    4        5   6   ...  8   9         10  11  12  13  14
0     google  nil  nil  nil  nil  balance  33  ...  30  23  research  19  22  25  37
1  microsoft  nil  nil  nil  nil  balance  10  ...  -1   1  research   9  15  21  23
2      apple  nil  nil  nil  nil  balance  34  ...  38  38  research   2   3   2   6
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest create new column with [`DataFrame.insert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html) and `ffill` and then create `MultiIndex` for only numeric years columns:

```
s = df['name'].mask(df['name'].isin(['investment','expense','research','rating'])).ffill()
df.insert(0, 'comp', s)
df = df[df['name'] != s]
df = df.set_index(['comp','name']).astype(int)
print (df)
                      2016  2017  2018  2019
comp      name                              
google    investment    56    61    62    68
          expense       23    25    32    45
          research      19    22    25    37
          rating         9     9     9     9
microsoft investment    60    70    69    81
          expense       50    60    70    80
          research       9    15    21    23
          rating         9     9     9     9
apple     investment    90    90    92    92
          expense       56    55    54    54
          research       2     3     2     6
          rating         9     8     9     9
```

then you can subtract by [`DataFrame.xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html), with create new `MultiIndex` by `balance` string:

```
df1 = df.xs('investment', level=1) - df.xs('expense', level=1)
df1 = df1.assign(name='balance').set_index('name', append=True)
print (df1)
                   2016  2017  2018  2019
comp      name                           
google    balance    33    36    30    23
microsoft balance    10    10    -1     1
apple     balance    34    35    38    38
```

And last join together by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
df = pd.concat([df, df1], sort=True).sort_index()
print (df)
                      2016  2017  2018  2019
comp      name                              
apple     balance       34    35    38    38
          expense       56    55    54    54
          investment    90    90    92    92
          rating         9     8     9     9
          research       2     3     2     6
google    balance       33    36    30    23
          expense       23    25    32    45
          investment    56    61    62    68
          rating         9     9     9     9
          research      19    22    25    37
microsoft balance       10    10    -1     1
          expense       50    60    70    80
          investment    60    70    69    81
          rating         9     9     9     9
          research       9    15    21    23
```